# Error when running adt bundle on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: android, adt

when I run Eclipse on Ubuntu I faced with the following error

i'm sorry for bad speak english

image :[bayanbox.ir/id/5851514597346971673?view](http://bayanbox.ir/id/5851514597346971673?view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close Eclipse, try to run the following in terminal than open eclipse again:

sudo chmod +x -R /home/abbasalim/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130219/ && chmod 777 -R /home/abbasalim/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130219/